# Add images dynamicaly asp net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, browser

I am building a simple image gallery using ASP.NET MVC 4. What is the best way in Create method to get images from users pc? I mean is there a way to open file explorer in browser and then just copy selected file to /Content/Images folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way in Create method to get images from users pc?

Using a file input control and having your action take the file:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

Then your post action would be:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    //do whatever with the image
}
```

> I mean is there a way to open file explorer in browser and then just copy selected file to /Content/Images folder?

No, not into the Content/Images folder. You should consider a hosting solution/database to store these images.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. But could explain me why Content foled is bad idea? Guys from msdn tutorials used it.

Comment: @AlexDefine The Content folder isn't a bad idea (it's standard practice, it comes with the MVC project template), adding stuff to it dynamically however isn't the best idea.